# Contextual Action Bar appears white(no background) on one device but ok on the others

Tags: android, contextual-action-bar

I'm new to android, but this thing I don't think that is related to experience. 
When I long press an item in my list to show the CAB, it appears with white background. I can see the buttons on the bar only when long pressing them, otherwise everything is invisible.I am using the same style file on 2 different apps and the other one is ok. Also this happens only on one device.
Any ideas?

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!-- Base application theme. -->

<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/background_activated_drawer</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>



<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background"  tools:ignore="NewApi">@color/RTL_light_grey</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@color/RTL_red</item>
    <item name="background">@color/RTL_dark_grey</item>
</style>

<style name="OverlayText">
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">4px</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">4px</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:shadowColor">@color/RTL_dark_grey</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx">4</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">4</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">5</item>
</style>
```

the contextual bar code

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = super.onCreateView(inflater, parent, savedInstanceState);
    ListView listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    listView.setChoiceMode(listView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
    listView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.tasks_context, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            TaskAdapter adapter = (TaskAdapter) getListAdapter();
            TasksStorage mStorage = TasksStorage.getsTaskStorage(getActivity());
            switch (item.getItemId()) {

                case R.id.menu_item_delete:

                    for (int i = adapter.getCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                        if (getListView().isItemChecked(i))
                            mStorage.deleteTask(adapter.getItem(i));

                    }

                    //MessageBox.getMsgBox(getActivity()).saveMessages(SAVE_M);

                    //MessageBox.getMsgBox(getActivity()).saveMessages(SAVE_D);

                    mode.finish();
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {

        }
    });
    return v;
}
```

Comment: Are you using appcompat? Post your toolbar/actionbar layout code and styles

Comment: Yes I'm using appcompat, the Contextual action bar is the standard one, anyway I'll edit the question adding the code